# C++ wrong result of mathematical expression

Tags: c++, integer-division

I have to calculate some simple mathematical expression, but when I do it in one row, the result always will be zero. But the correct result is obviously not zero. And its interesting but when I separate the parts of expression, I get the correct answer.
Later I will divide with this result, so it should not be 0.

The expression is like this:

```
(X-X1)/(X2-X1)
```

In this case the *delta*: 0

```
double delta = (x - x1) / (x2 - x1);
```

But this way the *delta* will be correct:

```
double top = x - x1;
double bottom = x2 - x1;
double delta = top/bottom;
```

Do you have any idea, how could this happen?

Comment: I take it x, x1 and x2 are integer values, and `x2-x1` is greater than `x-x1`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I didn't bother learning C before hacking on the Linux kernel](http://google.com/search?q=integer+division+c)

Comment: Yes, they are unsigned long int and yes, x2-x1 is the greater.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a typical case of "integer division used to make a float value". If `x`, `x1` and `x2` are all integers, then the compiler should, according to the rules of C and C++ use integer calculations to calculate `x-x1` and `x2-x1`, and then divide the differences of those as integer division. If `x2-x1` is greater than `x-x1`, then the result is zero [assuming positive values like 7/14. -14 / -7 is obviously 2].

The easy fix is to convert the type of one expression to a floating point type:

```
double delta = static_cast<double>(x - x1) / (x2 - x1);
```

Comment: And by "integer division" it is meant that the answer is truncated, that is, the whole part of the answer is kept and the remainder is discarded. So `1/2` gives 0 with a remainder of 1 which is thrown out, giving `1 / 2 == 0`.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood the problem.
(I did not know how to describe my problem well, thats why I asked the question.)

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, integer / integer, result is still integer, then convert integer to double.

In the second case, double / double, then you get correct result.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you are performing `int / int` which will result in a `int` value. So, if your denominator is larger than the numerator, the result will be truncated to 0.

In the second case, you are evaluating a `double/double` expression which will evaluate to a `double` value, hence preserving the fractional and integer parts.

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast the integer division to double. 
  [type casting](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/44-type-conversion-and-casting/)